# How to change date format (Day of week, Month, Day, Year) to a pandas readable format?

Tags: python, pandas

One of my columns in a pandas dataframe has dates formatted like so:

Saturday, April 29th, 2017

How would I change this to a pandas readable date type so that I can sort by date?

(python 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `to_datetime`. see example below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["Saturday, April 29th, 2017", "Wednesday, March 22nd, 2017"]})
print df.head()

# conversion to pandas date time
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
print df.head()

# Sorting by Date
print "sorted by Date"
print df.sort_values(['date']).head()
```

results in

```
                          date
0   Saturday, April 29th, 2017
1  Wednesday, March 22nd, 2017
        date
0 2017-04-29
1 2017-03-22
sorted by Date
        date
1 2017-03-22
0 2017-04-29
```